# AndroidStudio Android device USB debugging

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I faced an annoying problem with the latest version of Android Studio and most of my test Android Devices.

Whenever I connect my device to MacBook via USB, it works properly during some time, but unexpectedly it drops the connection and I am not able to see the previously connected devices in both Android Studio and ADB console command outputs.

Sometimes I can fix it by disconnecting and connecting the USB cable. Sometimes only if I revoke all previously connected devices from settings it starts to work.

I tried different devices and different wires. What I mentioned:

1. Any time I see an alert like "Allow USB debugging" on my phone, it has different RSA fingerprint, but at the same time rsa bup in `.android/adb` directory was not changed.
2. Today I faced first behavior, the device had a connection and lost it. And now I cannot discover the device via ADB, I followed "Troubleshoot device connection issues" pressed Rescan devices, and I can see the result in that dialog:

```
Android Studio detected 2 device(s)
Found 2 USB device(s) not recognized as Android devices:
Apple T1 Controller 
Pixel 2
```

But Pixel 2 is an Android device. Do you have any ideas about what could be the reason for that behavior?

Comment: In developer Settings on the android device, try to set "Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode" to on, I had a similiar issue and this solved it, sometimes the android device when you connect it it goes into charge only mode, if your phone does not have this option you can just double check if the device is not in charge only mode, change it "transfer files" mode or something similiar nor sure about the exact naming for these options on the pixel phones

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help for me(